# How to upload file to sharepoint liste using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sharepoint-online

i want to upload file to my liste SharePoint using nodejs
help me

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Pnp js:[Working in Nodejs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/nodejs-support/)

Authentication :[Authentication in Nodejs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/authentication/server-nodejs/)

1. [Adding Files](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#adding-files)
2. [AddUsingPath](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#addusingpath)

PnPjs is a collection of fluent libraries for consuming SharePoint, Graph, and Office 365 REST APIs in a type-safe way. You can use it within SharePoint Framework, Nodejs, or any JavaScript project.

Comment: yes it's good thank you , but i start work with sprrequest module and i want some  idea to upload file with sprrequest

Comment: is authentication required? is giving 404

Comment: You cannot access the required resources without authentication, because the version is updated, please look for the corresponding information on the new official website.

Answer (score 0):

Using `spsave` and `sppull` should do the trick.

This is an example project for what you are trying to achieve: [github.com/drass/node-sharepoint-file-sharing](https://github.com/drass/node-sharepoint-file-sharing)